# не выводится текст помогите

Tags: python

У меня проблема, что последняя строчка куда не выводится.
То есть пользователь должен нажать клавишу T и в строку ввести help, и ему должен высветится текст, который почему то не высвечивается
Помогите.
Код:

```
import msvcrt  
import sys    
print("Нажмите T, чтобы открыть строку по вводу команд.")    
print("Чтобы узнать действия клавиш - введите 'help' в строку для команд.")    

def comandinput():    
    input("Введите команду: ")    
def whatpressedkey():   
    print("Нажата клавиша: ", ord(pressedKey))    

while True:  
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()  
    if ord(pressedKey) == ord('q'):       
        sys.exit()  
    elif ord(pressedKey) == ord("t"):  
        comandinput()    
    elif ord(pressedKey) == ord("h"):  
        whatpressedkey()     
    elif comandinput() == 'help':  
        print("Нажмите клавишу Q, чтобы выйти")
```

Comment: А что такое `gjvjubnt`?

Answer (score 1):

Тогда вам нужно обработку команды поместить в соответствующую ветку.
И у вас то, что вводится через `input` никуда не попадает в итоге. Так что примерно так:

```
def comandinput():    
    return input("Введите команду: ") # <- результат ввода нужно вернуть
  
while True:  
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()  
    if ord(pressedKey) == ord('q'):       
        sys.exit()  
    elif ord(pressedKey) == ord("t"):  
        command = comandinput() # <- запомним результат ввода
        if command == 'help':   # <- и проверим его
            print("Нажмите клавишу Q, чтобы выйти")     
    elif ord(pressedKey) == ord("h"):  
        whatpressedkey()
```

Comment: Уже практически дописал ответ!..